# unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils (running groovy script)

Tags: groovy

On Ubuntu with groovy:

```
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.1.9 JVM: 11.0.10 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

I have this script:

**myScript.groovy**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils

String charset = (('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')).join()
Integer length = 9
String randomString1 = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
String randomString2 = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
String randomString3 = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
```

From terminal I run it:

```
$ groovy sampleScript.groovy 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1 (file:/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib/groovy-2.1.9.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/samples/myScript.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
   ^
```

If I search for that in maven central I get:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.showthat</groupId>
  <artifactId>DHStringUtils</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.5</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

I have then tried to update my script with:

```
@Grab(group='io.github.showthat', module='DHStringUtils', version='0.1.5')
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils

String charset = (('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')).join()
Integer length = 9
String randomString1 = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
String randomString2 = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
String randomString3 = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
```

But that gives:

```
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: io.github.showthat#DHStringUtils;0.1.5: not found]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: io.github.showthat#DHStringUtils;0.1.5: not found]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAc
```

Based on:
https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.apache.commons.lang

I have also tried with:

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.directory.studio', module='org.apache.commons.lang', version='2.6')
```

But that gives:

```
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.studio#org.apache.commons.lang;2.6: not found]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.apache.directory.studio#org.apache.commons.lang;2.6: not found]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from your very old Groovy version you inherited some old
scripts.  The packages of `apache-commons` has changed over time.  The
`RandomStringUtils` are now part of

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-lang3', version='3.12.0')
```

And the package changed to:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils
```

(note the `3` at the end of `lang`).

I'd advise to update the deps and adjust the code.  If you have to have
to stick with the old code, you might have to search for the file via
findjar or other sites and only take groups/artifacts that clearly state
"apache commons".  Anything else might just have copied it and might
not even be complete.  So I'd stay clear of anything non-apache-commons.